# Screen freezes whenever I open new Programm

Tags: 22.04, freeze, mouse-pointer

**Ryzen 5 5600, Radeon 6600, Gigabyte Gaming b550 x v2, UBUNTU 22.04.4 LTS**

Whenever I click onto an application running In the background with my cursor, the whole screen including my cursor freezes for about 2 seconds (E.g at the moment I'm writing this question, and whenever I click into PyCharm, the screen freezes). This also occurs if I start applications or I'm pausing/starting MP4s in the Browser and much more.

I hope you can share your ideas on how to fix this issue, since its getting really annoying.

Many thanks in advance

-Niko